# How to test if a user has SELECTED a file to upload?

Tags: php, file, upload

on a page, i have :

```
if (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {
    $dossier     = 'upload/';
    $fichier     = basename($_FILES['logo']['name']);
    $taille_maxi = 100000;
    $taille      = filesize($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']);
    $extensions  = array('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg');
    $extension   = strrchr($_FILES['logo']['name'], '.');

    if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
        $erreur = 'ERROR you  must upload the right type';
    }

    if($taille>$taille_maxi) {
         $erreur = 'too heavy';
    }

    if(!empty($erreur)) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, if the users wants to edit information WITHOUT uploading a LOGO, it raises an error : 'error you must upload the right type'

**So, if a user didn't put anything in the inputbox in order to upload it, i don't want to enter in these conditions test.**

i tested :
`if (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])` and `if (isset($_FILES['logo']['name'])`

but both doesn't seems to work.

Any ideas?

edit : maybe i wasn't so clear, i don't want to test if he uploaded a logo, i want to test IF he selected a file to upload, because right now, if he doesn't select a file to upload, php raises an error telling he must upload with the right format.

thanks.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can check this with:

```
if (empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {
    // No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}
```

Or you can use a javascript construction that only enables the upload/submit button whenever the upload field has a value other then an empty string ("") to avoid submission of the form with no upload at all.

Answer (score 35):

There is a section in php documentation about [file handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). You will [find](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) that you can check various errors and one of them is

```
UPLOAD_ERR_OK
    Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
<...>
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
    Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
```

In your case you need code like

```
if ($_FILES['logo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { ... }
```

or

```
if ($_FILES['logo']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) { ... }
```

You should consider checking (and probably providing appropriate response for a user) for other various errors as well.

Comment: @Tristan open your eyes and see: Value: 4; **No file was uploaded**

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel  oooops, indeed, i'm sorry, maybe it's time i put my glasses ;p

Comment: I checked this out for myself. It is indeed the correct way to check for such a case.

Also Note: "If no file is selected for upload in your form, PHP will return $_FILES['userfile']['size'] as 0, and $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] as none." (From the PHP Documentation) http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 14):

You should use [is_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'])](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to make sure that the file was indeed uploaded through a POST.

Comment: i added some information on my post. if you can look at it. thx

Answer (score 7):

I would test `if (file_exists($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']))` and see if it works.

Or, more approperately (thanks Baloo): `if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']))`

Comment: i added some information on my post. if you can look at it. thx

Answer (score 2):

We Could Use

For Single file:

```
if ($_FILES['logo']['name'] == "") {
    // No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}
```

For Multiple files:

```
if ($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'][0] == "") {
    // No files were selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
if($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]=="") {}
```

this can be used
No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here in if body
echo "no file selected";

Answer (score -3):

```
if ($_FILES['logo']['error'] === 0)
```

**is the only right way**

Comment: This is contrary to what the PHP Documentation states. This will actually evaluate to true if the file was uploaded successfully.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php