# Submit a form with file input left blank

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I am submitting a form where I am updating the `state id`, `city name` and `city image`.

When I only update the image, it works.
When I update `state id` and `city name` and want my old image to remain the same, the photo field become blank in the database.

My PHP code is like this:

```
 <?php 

if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['submit'] == "Update")
{
        extract($_POST);
        if($_FILES['photo'])
        {
        $cityimg = upload_file($_FILES['photo'],'cityimg/','image','N','true','thumb/', 100, 100);
        $sql = "UPDATE city SET mcid = '$mcid', city_name = '$city_name', photo = '$cityimg' WHERE cid = '$cid'";
        }
        else
        {
        $sql = "UPDATE city SET mcid = '$mcid', city_name = '$city_name' WHERE cid = '$cid'";
        }
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result)
        {
            $msg = "City Updated Successfully.";
        }
}

?>
```

I think that my loop is having some problem.

Comment: Your saying when your `else{}` is carried out your `photo` column gets emptied for that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test if a file was uploaded in a different way. For example, this will make sure that **no error occurred** during the file upload (and if there was any) :

```
if($_FILES['photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    // A file was uploaded and there is no error
}
```

If you only want to test **if no file was selected**, you could use `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`.

[More info on file upload error messages](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

This should work for you :

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['submit'] == "Update")
{
        extract($_POST);

        // If image was uploaded
        if($_FILES['logo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {
            $cityimg = upload_file($_FILES['photo'],'cityimg/','image','N','true','thumb/', 100, 100);
            $sql = "UPDATE city SET mcid = '$mcid', city_name = '$city_name', photo = '$cityimg' WHERE cid = '$cid'";
        }

        // If no image was uploaded
        else
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE city SET mcid = '$mcid', city_name = '$city_name' WHERE cid = '$cid'";
        }
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result)
        {
            $msg = "City Updated Successfully.";
        }
}
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958167/how-to-test-if-a-user-has-selected-a-file-to-upload) for more details