# CodeIgniter - last else if statement fail to meet the condition

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, if-statement

I think it's just a simple mistake I've made, but until now I still can't get the solution why my last else if {} statement does not execute when it meets the condition.

It's my form. I have 3 form elements as options for users to enter value. They can choose either to upload which are text, photo, or movie. Here is my PHP:

```
if ( $this->input->post('text') !== '') {

   //this executes fine when it meets the condition

} else if ( $this->input->post('photo') !== '' ) {

   // this also works fine

} else if ( $this->input->post('video') !== '' ) {

   /* however, I can't get to this condition when 
   the user chooses to upload the movie.
   It always go the second condition.
   */

}
```

Edit:

Here's my view:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>action/post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li class="active">
              <a href="#status" data-toggle="tab">Update Status</a>
         </li>
         <li>
              <a href="#photos" data-toggle="tab">Post Photos</a>
         </li>
         <li>
              <a href="#videos" data-toggle="tab">Post Videos</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="status">
              <textarea name="text"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="photos">
              <input type="file" name="photo" class="input" />
              <input type="text" name="photos-detail" placeholder="description" />
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="videos">
              <input type="file" name="video" class="input" />
              <input type="text" name="videos-detail" placeholder="description" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="post">Post</button>
 </form>
```

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: what does a var_dump($_POST) give you (before the if statements)?

Comment: Can you paste the code in your view?

Comment: To test if a file form element has been posted refer to this [answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958167/how-to-test-if-a-user-has-selected-a-file-to-upload

Comment: Thanks so much. +1 for this

Answer (score 2):

You cant check file inputs reliably like that. I usually check the file size to see if anything has been uploaded, so you could do something like this (should work):

```
if ( $this->input->post('text') !== '') {    
   //code   
} else if((isset($_FILES["photo"]["size"])) && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > 0)){   
   // code 2    
} else if((isset($_FILES["video"]["size"])) && ($_FILES["video"]["size"] > 0)){    
    // code 3    
}
```

**NOTE**
You can't just check the file size or you will get undefined index error - hence the isset()

Answer (score 0):

If I use the same code the result that I get is that my view show me the entire code line.

```
if ( $usuario->party !== '') {
   <a href="<?php echo base_url('vincular/party') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/link/sprite1_13.png') ?>"></a>
} else {
   <a href="<?php echo base_url('vincular/party') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/link/party.png') ?>"></a>
}
```

If I don´t use  my code works fine:

```
<?php foreach ($usuarios->result() as $usuario) { ?>
    <div id="cuerpo" class="cuerpoMyPerfil">
        <div id="columna1">                    
            <div id="contenColumn1" class="corner">
                <div class="myFoto">
                    <img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/testimonials/user.jpg') ?>" width="100%" height="auto" alt="nombre" />                </div>
                <div class="myNombre">
                    <?php
                    echo $usuario->nombre . "<br/>";
                    echo $usuario->apellidos;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="myDescripcion">
                    <?php echo $usuario->acerca; ?>
                </div>
if ( $usuario->party !== '') {
   <a href="<?php echo base_url('vincular/party') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/link/sprite1_13.png') ?>"></a>
} else {
   <a href="<?php echo base_url('vincular/party') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/link/party.png') ?>"></a>
}

                <dl class="dl-vertical">
                    <!-- Verificar que tenga valores en la tabla vincular
                    Si lo trae, poner el ícono prendido, de lo contrario el apagado-->
                    <dt>

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('vincular/dating') ?>"><img class="pull-right" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/link/love.png') ?>"></a></dt>
                    <dt><a href="<?php echo base_url('vincular/network') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/link/network.png') ?>"></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('vincular/friends') ?>"><img class="pull-right" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/link/friends.png') ?>"></a></dt>
                </dl>

            </div>
            <div class='myTextInvi'>
                <div class='textInvitacionActual floatL'>Tienes Invitaciones disponibles</div>
                <div class='numInvitacionActual floatL' ><?php echo $usuario->disponibles; ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class='myBtnInvi'>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('oneperfil/invite') ?>">
                    <div class='textBtnInvitacion'>ENVIAR INVITACIÓN</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```