# Check if user has selected a file to upload

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script where the system checks if the user has selected a file to upload before uploading anything. The issue I'm having is that even if I don't select a file, the system echoes that a file has been uploaded successfully. See code below:

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");

if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) {

    $loggedinuser = $_GET['bid'];   
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO upload (personalid, file, type, size) values ((select personalid from person where username='$loggedinuser'), '$file', '$file_type', '$file_size')") or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    if($sql){
        header("location:upload.php?msg0=Document upload successful.");     
    } elseif( !file_exists($_FILES['file']['name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name']) ) {
        header("location:upload.php?msg1=Document upload failed.");
    }
}
?>
<!-- need to comment -->
```

Updated Version - 16:34 (13/11/2015)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include("dbconfig.php");
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){

if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){

    echo 'error!';

} else {

$loggedinuser = $_GET['bid'];

$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO upload (personalid, file, type, size) values ((select personalid from person where username='$loggedinuser'), '$file', '$file_type', '$file_size')") or die (mysqli_error($conn));

if($sql){
    header("location:upload.php?msg0=Document upload successful.");     
}
else {
    header("location:upload.php?msg1=Document upload failed.");
}
}
}


 ?>
<!-- need to commentt -->
```

I have done some research online and I've come across some discussions that mention you can us `file_exists` or `is_uploaded_file` - I'm not sure if I'm using them correctly. Please do let me know how I can check if a user has selected a file before uploading.

Thanks,

Sohail.

Comment: Just check if `$_FILES['file']['name']` is not empty

Comment: The only checking you could do in this respect would be using javascript because `file_exists` and `is_uploaded_file` etc would only be invoked after the submission..

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']))` is how I check for files being uploaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if a user has SELECTED a file to upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958167/how-to-test-if-a-user-has-selected-a-file-to-upload)

Comment: You should check your syntax. You appear to have syntax errors as well. `error_reporting( E_ALL );`

Comment: @Dale I added that in and pressed upload, it produced a blank screen.

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: @Chris I placed that error reporting statement in my php file but its still giving me a blank screen... I'll paste the updated code in my question.

Comment: I would add an `exit();` if the file does not exists. It's curious that `error!` does not show even. I wonder if something else is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Well at the moment your statement is based only if the button is pushed as POST request, which it always will be.

I am not 100% on this but I am prepared to try and answer this.

```
$loggedinuser = $_GET['bid'];
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
}

if (isset($file) && isset($file_size) && isset(file_type)) {    
  SQL stuff;
}

if(isset($sql) && $sql){
    header("location:upload.php?msg0=Document upload successful.");     
} else {
    header("location:upload.php?msg1=Document upload failed.");
}
```

On a side note, can you not just ensure the field is required in the HTML?

Comment: Thank your for your efforts, but I have rectified the issue.

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif : What was the issue ?

Comment: In the past I usually just put required in the html part of the input

<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required>

I would be interested to know what was the outcome, I didn't test the above code my self it was from my head.